# GE dishwasher doesn't completely drain

Tags: dishwasher

My dishwasher fills with fresh water, and everything seems to work as expected except there always is leftover water. I can tell fresh water is being pumped in because the color and odor improves with each wash.

There is a small amount of food debris that I mostly removed from the screen basket. While I read in the manual that it is normal for "[a small amount of] water standing in the bottom of the tub", this is more than is normal from memory and from the fact that the water is dirty after a completed wash.

As the manual suggests, I cleaned the air gap, but like I said that seems unnecessary because the water never goes beyond the air gap. I have gotten it to drain three times after several more attempts to clean it out. We have never heard a motor hum while standing near it on completion of the cycle.

Do I need to clean the pump like this other [thread](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/67003/can-i-clean-out-a-ge-dishwasher-drain-pump) suggests? Do I rather need to purchase a replacement part? How can I diagnose the problem?

Model: GLD5654V00CS [manual](https://www.searspartsdirect.com/manual/1sahivj9py-000432/ge-gld5654v00cs-dishwasher)

Comment: If there is a float switch or air hose to a pressure switch to detect water level, check if the float or hose is blocked by food.

Comment: I just disconnected the drain hose. There is no visible blockage so far. When I lifted the hose the hose drained completely. The dishwasher dripped one small drop every half second or so, so I'll remove the drain pump next to see if there is a blockage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that a blockage got in the way of drainage. Now I know an eye dropper rubber nipple is about the same size as a GE dishwasher drain inlet.